# how to add details in specific column in list view

Tags: c#, listview

I wanna add details to watchers column like my following image.. I use following code to add those details.But it prints in 1st column.. could anybody tell me to do this.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGSIU.jpg)

Here's the code I've used:

```
private void addwatchers(string watchers)
{
   string[] row = { watchers };
   ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
   //ADD ITEMS
   listView1.Items.Add(item);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     string[] cwatchers = richTextBox2.Text.Split('\n');
     for (int i=0;i<cwatchers.Length;i++)
     {
         addwatchers(cwatchers[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: You're passing a single-item array to create the `ListViewItem` so it's only populating the first column. Create the row array first with all the column values and call the `addWatchers()` method once per line.

Comment: I did like that. but i cannot get the result that i want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `addWatchers()` you create a list view item (a row in the list view). You have several ways of creating such items. The one you're currently using is passing an array of string, which represents the column values (by position) to create each item.

What I'd do is to create the `ListViewItem` in the caller method instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cwatchers.Length; i++)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem(i.ToString()); //<-- arbitrarily using i as the value for the first column. You should use whatever makes sense to you.

    //TODO: add the sub item for the ID column
    item.SubItems.Add("");

    //Add in Watchers
    item.SubItems.Add(cwatchers[i]);

    //TODO: add the rest of the sub items

    //Add the item to the list view
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

You can safely get rid of the `addwatchers` method since it's only adding the corresponding subitem.

> UPDATE

If you already have the items created when you call addWatchers, then the only thing you need to do is iterate through the items in the list view and add the missing sub items.

Let's say you have added in a previous process all the items to the listview. And when you did that, you created the listview item with two columns.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] cwatchers = richTextBox2Text.Split('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < cwatchers.Length; i++)
    {
        //Get the listview item in i and add the sub item for the watchers.
        //this assumes that the list view item is created and contains two subitems so the next one to be added is the wawtchers.

        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(cwatchers[i]);

        //TODO: add the rest of the sub items
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How are you adding the previous items? If those are already there you'll have this issue. Is the listview empty at the beginning?

Comment: Where are you taking the IDs from? Are you adding them in a different moment?

Comment: these are ebay listings ids. i am going to check watchers. I have a method to check watchers. and getting watchers amounts per each IDs. I want to print those watchers on next column as parallel..

Comment: Seems like the items are already created, if that's the case, then do not create a new list view item but add the values to the existing one instead.

Comment: could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: I updated the answer assuming the items are already created. If that doesn't work for you, I'm afraid I can't help you anymore without seeing the specific way your creating the items.

Comment: Anything else you need here? I believe you've got this already. If it had helped you, please consider upvoting and marking as accepted.

Comment: listView1.Items[i+1].SubItems.Add(cwatchers[i]);  it works... edit like this,,